# How to get Google places geometry location data into firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, formik

I am using a React app to store some info into firebase/firestore on formik form submission. When the user enters a location, a react-google-autocomplete performs the autocomplete, then returns the properly formatted address, and a places.geometry.location latitude and longitude. On submission, I can console log or alert using JSON.stringify the latitude and longitude, but the console returns a firebase error saying the following: `FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field orggeometry in the document`

[Formik code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86jrZ.png)

This shows how I have coded my formik onSubmit etc.

[Input ref for the autocomplete, showing where my values for location are set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shoRT.png)

This show the input ref, and how the values are set. I have two of these. The way they are set up, I can currently submit the form after selecting a location in both of my autocomplete inputs and obtain the latitude and longitude numbers.

[Example of working latitude and longitude on my Origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuHse.png)

As you can see, the form has zero issues with the values. The problem is strictly with firebase. I have scoured Google searches, this website, Firebase docs, and Places/Maps docs. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of `orggeometry` in firebase?  where you're saving the data? Geographical Point is not recommended 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types
You can use a geohash, but you need to hash the location first. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries

Comment: It should be a string, I apologize if that doesn't properly answer the question as I'm not certain what you mean. As for Geographical Point, I have to use it per the project specifications, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after sleeping on it and spending some time working on it, I found a solution that fixed it for my case. The issue was that `place.geometry.location` returns an object with both latitude and longitude, which Firebase does not like. I tried to JSON.stringify the values of the entire form, which didn't fix it, however rewriting it as follows fixed it for my particular case.

`const { ref } = usePlacesWidget({apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE, onPlaceSelected: (place) => {setPlace(place); formik.setFieldValue("Origin", place.formatted_address); JSON.stringify(place.geometry.location) formik.setFieldValue("OriginGeometry", JSON.stringify(place.geometry.location))`

Now it returns a string that consists of the object itself, not the ideal fix in my opinion for anyone who wants a very clean looking database entry, but perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: If this resolves the problem for you, you can accept your own answer. 

Please consider formatting the code block to make it easier for anyone following your path.